# Sharepoint webpart-page versioning

Tags: sharepoint, versioning, web-parts

On webpart-pages it is possible modify the contained webparts over the Web by using **Site Actions->Edit page**.

Is there a possibility to view the version history of such a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  Unfortunatly the web part manager does not version changes so even if you do go back to an older version of the page the web parts will not revert back.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SharePoint 2010, versioning is now supported for web part configuration. Check out Maurice's post for more info: http://www.bluedoglimited.com/SharePointThoughts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=305